# Python modules collection from requirements txt

Tags: python, pip

I just have questions about downloading Python modules based on requirements.txt Let's say I have a bundle of folders A,B. Each folder contains some subdirectories within it.

Each folder contains `requirements.txt`, which contains a specific package:

```
$ cat requirements.txt
boto3
```

When I run a bash script, the script will always download the package from the internet, which takes time each time.

To increase build speed, instead of downloading packages from the internet,  how can I re-use the package until I change the version inside the `requirements.txt` file?

```bash
cat /workspace/source/A/Lambda/requirements.txt
boto3

cat /workspace/source/B/Lambda/requirements.txt
pymongo=4.6.0
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash
  startdir=(
  "/workspace/source/A/Lambda"
  "/workspace/source/B/Lambda")

   SRC_DIR=/workspace/source/src_lambda
   if [ ! -d $SRC_DIR ]
   then
      mkdir $SRC_DIR
    else
      echo "Source Python Modules Directory Cleaning"
      cd "$SRC_DIR" && rm -rf *.zip
      cd ..
    fi
    
    for dir in "${startdir[@]}"; do
    (
     cd "$dir" || continue
      for sub_dir in */ ; do
        cd "$sub_dir" || exit
        echo "---> Finding pip modules based on requirements.txt file"
        pip install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --implementation cp --python-version 3.11 --only-binary=:all: -r requirements.txt -t .
        zip -r "${sub_dir%/}.zip" .
        echo "---> Copying the zip files "${sub_dir%/}".zip into destination location "$SRC_DIR""
        cp -r "${sub_dir%/}".zip $SRC_DIR
        cd ..
      done
    )
    done
    echo "zip files has been moved to SRC_DIR"
```

Comment: I'm not an expert, but doesn't pip have a cache? Are you sure the files are being redownloaded every time?

Comment: Hi @wjandera, yes its downloading every time from the internet

Comment: Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.3

  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/

Comment: But how to add this inside the bash script ?